# How can I log which queries are in a distributed transaction on an MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, distributed-transactions

I am looking at migrating a database from a self-hosted cluster to Microsoft Azure SQL. I am aware that there are a few distributed transactions involved, which isn't supported on Azure SQL.

Is there a way that I can log all distributed transactions and their queries, so that I can inspect the client application and remove the requirement for distributed transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to track the [DTCTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/dtctransaction-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15) event in SQL Trace or XEvents.

Or you could just shut down MSTDC (not in production, of course) and see what fails.

Also note that updates to .NET's SqlClient enables some distributed transaction scenarios with Azure SQL Database without MSDTC.  See

[Distributed transactions across cloud databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview#installation-and-migration)

Comment: Whilst I like the option of turning off MSDTC, I know there are a few production critical places it's used. I also don't have a solid list of the client involved. The DTC Transaction event looks solid.